# How to insert 6 millions records less than 4 minutes in ASP.NET webforms and SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have to insert a large amount of data, and I am using `SqlBulkCopy`, but it is taking 20 minutes to process 5 millions records.

Is there any way to insert data more quickly?

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Perahps a database restore would be better? (60 seconds). On the other hand, such a type of operation would be  one time migration type of process - not something that you have to run on a frequent basis. If you have to often run such a process, then something is VERY wrong with the data process approach here . So, I not sure if a rate of 4000 records per second is "slow" or "low" in fact it looks to be VERY fast. I mean, lets say you found a way to increase speed by 25%? Well you then taking 16 minutes. Having to do this over and over is your problem here.

Comment: There's something wrong with your design probably. If such heavyweight operation is somehow triggered from asp.net, what will happen if somehow someone triggers two or three or more operations in the same time?

Comment: so, plz tell me the solution and which technology is best for these type of operations because my query in sql server  slow down